# Kafka poll and max.poll.interval.ms - Batch Processing best practices

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm having trouble with a KafkaConsumer's group offset skipping forwards while I'm in the middle of processing the information I've read and stored in memory.

Let's say we have a Kafka consumer built like this:

```
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootstrapServer);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class.getName());
```

And we set the poll to be `Consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(120))`. The consumer will process messages and store the data in memory. After a million records are read we want to process the data stored in memory.

```
while(true){
   recordRead.forEach(record -> {
      count++;
      //Store information
      if(count == 1000000){
         processKafkaMessages();
      }
   }
}

private void processKafkaMessages(){
   //Do something
}
```

However, the function `processKafkaMessages` takes a full hour to complete.

While I'm processing I do not want my consumer to to move to the next record on the topic - I want it to stay at the last offset we completed. What I'm seeing, however, is that as I'm processing the messages the groups offset gets moved, seeing this in the log:

`[2020-05-20 08:14:38,888] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-234624] Asynchronous auto-commit of offsets {my-topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=71240, metadata=''}} failed: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)`

After looking into this more I know that I can set my consumers `max.poll.interval.ms` property to be greater than an hour. However I don't want to hard code a value here. What if tomorrow it takes one hour and five minutes? I'll be in the same situation.

What I'm looking for, and have been unable to find, are best practices for consumers that deal with processing large amounts of data in batches - then doing something with that data. Should I manually keep track of and commit the offest, should my consumer pass the data off to another thread for analysis, set the `max.poll.interval.ms` to `Long.MAX_VALUE`, or is there a better way I'm not thinking of?

Another thing I'm confused on is how my `poll()` setting is somehow being run while in the middle of this hour long process? Does the consumer just know, innately, that the poll is set? Or am I completely wrong on that?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used java consumer.
Have you tried pausing the partitions before calling processKafkaMessages ? 
https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#pause(java.util.Collection)

Comment: I will have to test this today and get back to you. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: This seemed to work, ultimately. However in very extreme cases I still saw some weird offset behavior. I'm not sure if it's from the overall length of the process (one hour) or if I'm doing something wrong else where.